# Prove that $f=g$ except in a set of null measure on $ \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, measure-theory

$f,g:S \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable functions, $f \leq g$ on $S$ and $\int_{S} f = \int_{S} g$ then  $f=g$  except  in a set of null measure on $ \mathbb{R}^n$.
My attempt, let $\epsilon >0$, there is a partition $P$ of $S$,
Let $R$ be subrectangles formed by the partition.
we knows $f=g$ imply  $\int_{S} f = \int_{S} g$. but if $f < g$  hence $M_{R}(f) < M_{R}(g)$ in this mode $$S(g,P)-S(f,P) < \epsilon $$ My problem, can I choose the same rectangles that I used in $S(g,P)-S(f,P)$ to do the
covering of the set $\{f < g\}$

Comment: What can you say about $g - f$ and $\int_S g - f$?

Comment: I guess you want to say that for all $S$ the integrals coincide. Otherwise it is not true. Take for example $S=[-1,1], f=0, g(x)=x$.

Comment: Here $f\leq g$ is violated.

Comment: If $g=f$ then $f-g=0$ imply $\int_{S}f-g=0$. If $f<g$ then $S_{g,p}-S_{f,p}<\epsilon$ and using that integrals of $f$ and $g$ exist then $\int_{S} f-g <\epsilon$ that mean $\int_{S} f-g \rightarrow 0$ and $f-g\neq 0$ im confuse, can you help me Chris?

Comment: Well, we don't know if $g = f$ yet; that's what we're trying to prove. Consider instead $g - f$ which, by hypothesis, is nonnegative. Then $\int_S (g - f) = 0$, also by hypothesis. So we have that the integral of a nonnegative function is zero - what does this say about the function?

Comment: Well the function have to be zero!! Thank you Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Chebishev-Markov's inequality
$$\lambda\big(g-f>\frac{1}{n}\big)=\lambda\big(|g-f|>\frac{1}{n}\big)\leq n\int_{\big\{g-f>\tfrac{1}{n}\big\}} (g-f)\,d\lambda\leq  n\int_S (g-f)\,d\lambda=0$$
since $f\leq g$, and $f,g$ are integrable. ($\lambda$ is the measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, Lebesgue measure in the present case by the looks of the OP notation)

Thus $\lambda(g\neq f)=\lambda(g-f>0)=\lambda\Big(\bigcup_n\{g-f>\frac{1}{n}\}\Big)=0$
as the union of sets of measure $0$ is of measure $0$.